# SSD not being detected in boot order after restoring image into it with Clonezilla

Tags: clonezilla, windows-11

I have been trying to create a golden image with the default settings and apps in Windows 11 to deploy throughout multiple PCs. After researching about it a lot I decided to create a Master in Virtualbox, sysrep the image and then capture it using Clonezilla. Everything was going fine, I successfully captured the image and then went on to deploy it also using Clonezilla. I used the -k1 option and deployed it into an SSD, but now the aforementioned SSD does not appear in the BIOS Boot order, and this is the problem that I ultimately need fixing.

I also tried to do the restoring process again, and the SSD does appear in Clonezilla Live, but not on the BIOS Boot order.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 drive cloned from Clonezilla image will not boot](https://serverfault.com/questions/980018/windows-10-drive-cloned-from-clonezilla-image-will-not-boot)